# How to structure the database for an e-commerce application?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am making an e-commerce web application. The following are the things that I have planned.

1. `products` table to contain only few columns viz. `id`, `name`, `code`, `SKU_no`.
2. `meta_information_products` table containing columns viz. `id`, `product_id` [foreign key to `products` table], `meta_title`, `meta_keywords`, `meta_description`.
3. `measurement_product` table containing columns viz. `id`, `product_id`, `width`, `height`, `weight`, `length`
4. And similarly other tables in relation to products.

So my questions are:

1. Shall I create different `Model` for each of the points above and
   then create the `One-To-One` relationship with `products` and
   related table ? Or shall I create only one Model called `Product` and declare all the fields in just one table `product`.
2. If I create different models for `Product`, what should be the name of the method to be declared for creating the `One-To-One` relationship, and same with `Product` Model.

For example, consider the following: I have created two models called `Product` and `MetaInformationProduct` and I have created relationship with both the tables. Now how do I `name` the method for the following:

```
class Product extends Model {
    ...

    public function methodName() {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }

    ...
}
```

And for `MetaInformationProduct`:

```
class MetaInformationProduct extends Model {
    ...

    public function methodName() {
        $this->hasOne('App\Product');
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess Stack Overflow is not the best place to ask questions of this kind, since your questions do not necessarily have right or wrong answers. There are multiple possible ways to go about constructing your app's data structure, and ultimately it all boils down to one's personal style of coding. So almost every developer would have an original 'right answer' to your questions.

Here's what I think. Why do you need three separate tables for all that data? As far as I can see, all three tables contain data related one-to-one to a single product. That means more complicated models and relations in development, and more resources and longer execution time in production. You could avoid all that if you create one `products` table with the following columns: `id`, `code`, `SKU_no`, `name`, `title`, `description`, `width`, `height`, `length`, `weight`. That will simplify your models significantly and reduce the number of queries trifold.

Additionally, I think I can spot a piece of bad practice in your table structure. In your current `meta_information_products` table you have a column named `meta_keywords`. I'm guessing that that field would contain multiple keywords of a product. This negates the benefit of relational database structure and will give you headaches down the road. Instead, I would create one `products` table as I described in the previous paragraph, then another table titled `keywords`, with the following columns: `id`, `keyword`. Lastly, you'd need a relational table titled `keyword_product` with the following columns: `id`, `keyword_id`, `product_id`. This gives you the ability for one product to have multiple keywords, and for one keyword to be assigned to multiple products. It's a well known 'Many to many' relation, and you can read more about it in the [Laravel's official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many).

In general, you should create one model for one database table, except for the relational tables. So in case you do as I would, you would then need two models: `Product` and `Keyword`. For its content, it's best that you refer to the link in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for your input sir. But to give you the information, there are many other information related to the products that needs to be taken into consideration. I have just showed the piece of the data. There will be more data coming like `product's general information`, `taxation`, `shipping_information`, etc. And I want to avoid more than 12 columns per table.

Comment: I understand, but a general rule of thumb is, if the info is in `one-to-one` relation with a product, then it belongs to the `products` table. If the relation is not `one-to-one`, as with the keywords and, I presume, `taxation` and `shipping_information`, then you should create one of the available relationships from here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Comment: I'd make a change here: `keyword_product` doesn't need an `id` - just make the two foreign keys into a composite foreign key. You only need the separate primary key if you wish to refer to this bridge table from elsewhere.

Comment: @user3514160 Dont worry about 12 columns... if you are going to use soft deletes you are going to end up with 20 or more columns anyway, stick to the answer I find it good +1. Read a lot about relations, see laracasts about it its worth the buck! And study study study (if you are new). I enjoy the most this part of programming myself. (ER model, database stuff etc.)

Comment: Okay.. Thank you everyone for clearing out my query.

Comment: user3514160 if you have any additional questions, don't hesitate to ask :)